# Animate height, not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I'm changing the content of a div dynamically, using jquery
The height of the div should change/animate according to the new content

I found some lines that work perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and on iPhone.
But in IE the content animates but it goes out "of the box". Meaning.. the height of the div does'nt change

```
var $mydiv = $('#venues');
$mydiv.css('height', $mydiv.height());
$mydiv.html(TheDynamicContent);
if (!$mydiv.find("div.innerWrapper").length) { $mydiv.wrapInner('<div class="innerWrapper"/>'); }
$mydiv.animate({height: $('div:first',$mydiv).height()});
```

I have searched a lot trying to find alternatives/fixes, without luck..
What to do? ;)

UPDATE: It seemed that **curvycorners** was generating an extra div, which only IE was sensitive about. So this code is actually ok.

Comment: What version(s) of IE does it not work in?

Comment: IE 9 (filler text to be allowed to type a short comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following appears to work just fine for me (tested in IE10, 9, 8, and 7)

```
$("#venues")
  .css("height", function(){ return $(this).height(); })
  .html("This is much longer text to force the element to grow.")
  .wrapInner("<div/>")
  .animate({
    "height": $("div:first", "#venues").height()
  }, 1000);
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/inudaz/2/edit

*Warning: You may encounter an error on jsbin suggesting `$` is undefined. If this is the case, simply download the example (using Save > Download from within jsbin) and run it locally.*

**Solution:** The OP's project was making use of a jQuery plugin that modified the DOM in key areas, resulting in unexpected behavior. Disabling this plugin resolved the issue.

Comment: No change for me. The text goes out of the div, and the div itself still doesn't change height

Comment: @mowgli We have a problem then, because the code above works as-is for me. Did you try the demo on jsbin, or did you copy/paste this code into your own project? If you pasted this into your own project, you may have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: I tried both ;) On your demo the content doesn't change or animate at all (in IE). And in my own code the result is excactly as with my previous code

Comment: @mowgli And you are using IE9? Are there any errors in the console of your F12 Developer Tools?

Comment: I have a faulty IE? (more faulty than standard IE faultyness)

Comment: http://sampsonresume.com/labs/newHeights/ does not work for you? I'm testing it myself in IE9 and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yeah that works fine! Btw. I'm on Windows 7 64 bit. Have tried with both 64bit and 32bit version of IE. Maybe I should reinstall java

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9604/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-mowgli)

Comment: It seemed that curvycorners was generating an extra div, which only IE was sensitive about. Thank you Jonathan Sampson

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a delay ?

```
$mydiv.animate({height: $('div:first',$mydiv).height()}, 500);
```

Comment: That didn't work. I have edited my question. So it's "But in IE the content animates but it goes out "of the box". Meaning.. the height of the div does'nt change"